# Adding server side rendering to an existing React site created with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering, next.js

I've been building a site for a client using `CRA`(`create-react-app`) and `react-router` v4.2.0 and was unaware of the implications regarding google's SEO. When I index the page from Google Search Console, I get this:
[image: Google Search Console Result]

I found several similar issues which suggested adding `'babel-polyfill'` to  my entry point, but this only causes my root component to render in the console, not taking into account my react-router routes. I'm aware that `CRA` is not designed for `SSR`. I was hoping to find a workaround within `CRA`, or migrate gracefully to another library such as `Next.js` without having to rebuild the entire site. Let me know if any additional information is needed. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: have you tried googling a little bit? there are few articles like https://medium.com/bucharestjs/upgrading-a-create-react-app-project-to-a-ssr-code-splitting-setup-9da57df2040a https://medium.com/@cereallarceny/server-side-rendering-with-create-react-app-fiber-react-router-v4-helmet-redux-and-thunk-275cb25ca972 etc.

Comment: I've done quite a bit of googling. The method in the second article proved to no avail (lots of rather unhelpful errors when spinning up my server). I'll check out the first one thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try on https://github.com/antonybudianto/cra-universal/

It's a CLI companion for universal create-react-app, without eject + zero config by default.

```
$ cd my-cra-app
$ npm start // start CRA client
$ npx cra-universal start // start CRA server
```

For existing code, you need to customize, it depends on your app's stack. 
You can visit the repo's wiki for React router/redux integration on server.